# Tasker и ADB: удалённое включение/выключение созданного профиля

Tags: android-sdk, adb

Нужно удалённо выключить определённый профиль в Tasker, у меня он называется On.
Выдает ошибку "неудача при выполнении задачи передачи" при использовании этой команды:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK -e task_name on
```

Установка `tasker-proxy`  и использование вариаций следующей команды результатов не дало:

```
adb shell su -c am broadcast -a pl.bossman.taskerproxy.ACTION_TASK -e task_name on
```

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

В Tasker надо включить птичку - разрешить внешний доступ. И еще таскер не разрешает запускать "опасные" комманды - типа блокировка телефона, звонок и тп.